# Error with distinct, oracle and CLOB in Grails

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, clob

I have an application written in grails 2.2.5 that needs to connect with MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server depending on my customers. We have more than 1000 queries that uses distinct returning instances of classes.

Example:

```
import br.com.aaf.auditoria.*

def query="select distinct tipo from Atividade c join c.tipoAtividade tipo order by tipo.nome"

def ret=Atividade.executeQuery(query)
```

So far so good, but now I need to include some CLOBs columns in oracle to expand some fields from VarChar 4000. When I do that these queries stop working because of the problem that Oracle does not compare CLOB columns.

Error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

I understand that Grails/Hibernate uses all properties of the domain class to make the sql to send to the database and return as an instance of that class.
The case is that I only need to compare or group the id of the domain class to make a distinct, but I need the result to be an instance of the class and not the id, so I don´t need to change all the queries.

Any of you know a way to change the behaviour of a distinct in HQL even if I need to customize a dialect to capture what Hibernate is doing in transforming HQL in SQL?

What I´m thinking is capture the SQL, change it to return and group only the id of the instance and execute a "get" in the Domain class before return this to "executeQuery".

Answer (score 0):

The solution only fits to oracle db. You have to grant some privileges to your schema. "Create types" and " execute on DBMS_CRYPTO"

```
create table clob_test (id number, lob clob);

insert all 
  into clob_test values(1,'AAAAAAAA')
  into clob_test values (2,'AAAAAAAA')
  into clob_test values(3,'BBBBBBBB')
  into clob_test values(4,'BBBBBBBB')
  select * from dual;
commit;

CREATE OR REPLACE 
type wrap_lob as object(
  lob clob,
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_hash RETURN RAW
)
;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE BODY wrap_lob is

  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_hash RETURN RAW is
  begin
    return DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(lob,1);
  end;
end;
/


select tab.dist_lob.lob from (select distinct wrap_lob(lob) dist_lob from clob_test) tab;
```